# Orthogonal projections of real positive definite matrices and their determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, positive-definite

Consider an $n\times n$ positive definite real matrix $(m_{i, j}) = M\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. For an indexing set $I \subseteq [n]$, denote with $M_I$ the sub-matrix of $M$, consisting of coefficient $m_{i, j}$ s.t. $i, j \in I$. In other words, $M_I$ is obtained via an orthogonal projection of $M$ onto the sub-space indexed by $I$.

Find a sufficient (possibly necessary) condition on the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ of $M$, by which it holds $\det(M_J) \leq \det (M_I)$ for all indexing sets s.t. $I \subseteq J$.

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient condition is that all $\lambda_i\le1$.  This follows immediately from [Cauchy's Interlacing Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) (see also [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.324.2243&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). If $I\subset J$ the eigenvalues of $M_I$ can be matched with $|I|$ of those of $M_J$ in such a way that the $M_I$ ones are greater than their $M_J$ partners.  Since the unmatched values belonging to $M_J$ are all $\le 1$, the result follows.